# What is the difference between blobtargetoption and blobwriteoption

Tags: google-cloud-storage, blob, target

I was practicing some google cloud upload, while creating the blob I see two options to set `BlobWriteOption.predefinedAcl(Storage.PredefinedAcl acl)` and `BlobTargetOption.predefinedAcl(Storage.PredefinedAcl acl)`

I'm curious to know the difference and went through:

> https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Bucket.BlobTargetOption.html

and

> https://dev.ionic.com/sdk_docs/ionic_gcs_sdk/java/version_0.9.1/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.BlobWriteOption.html

but couldn't get much difference between two.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn’t find much, but it seems like the BlobWriteOption is used when input streams are involved.

For instance on this [doc](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Bucket.html) both methods with streams are using BlobWriteOption

```
public Blob create(String blob,
                   InputStream content,
                   String contentType,
                   Bucket.BlobWriteOption... options)

public Blob create(String blob,
                   InputStream content,
                   Bucket.BlobWriteOption... options)
```

As opposed to BlobTargetOption don’t have input streams

```
public Blob create(String blob,
                   byte[] content,
                   String contentType,
                   Bucket.BlobTargetOption... options)


public Blob create(String blob,
                   byte[] content,
                   Bucket.BlobTargetOption... options)
```

It looks like this pattern repeats on these docs as well:

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage/1.14.0/source-code/com/google/cloud/storage/Bucket.java

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/storage/BucketTest.java